# How to show $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n(1+(k)/n)^3(1/n)=15/4$?

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

How would I show $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n(1+(k)/n)^3(1/n)=15/4?$$

My attempt is using the Riemann Sum technique. We know $(1+(k)/n)^2=f(\zeta_k)$ and $(1/n)=\Delta x$. So the definite integral goes from $a$ to $b$ where $b-a=1$.

I think I should find the formula for $$\sum_{k=1}^nk^3.$$ This would be $1+8+27+\cdots+n^3$... but then I get stuck.

Comment: Ask Faulhaber...

Comment: As a Riemannian sum, $\int_0^1(1+x)^3dx=15/4$.

Comment: This is odd, you are asked to find the limit of some sums, thus you turn to integrals (good idea), but then, instead of evaluating the relevant integral (a trivial task), you suddenly make a U-turn to come back to sums... where you declare you are stuck.